# Unmet dependencies, Installing ROS indigo, ros-indigo-desktop-full

Tags: dependencies, ubuntu-14.04, ros, failed-installation

I am trying to install ROS Indigo on a Oracle VM VirtualBox machine, however, i came across this issue. When i try to run the command `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full` i get this message

> `Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
>                              Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
>                              Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
>                              Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
>    unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                           Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

To mention, I am following the instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu and have done all steps from 1.1 to 1.4 and as is seems i have some dependency issue i tried installing additional system dependencies mentioned in point 1.4 `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-trusty mesa-common-dev-lts-trusty libxatracker-dev-lts-trusty libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-trusty libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty libgbm-dev-lts-trusty libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty`

Still, i get an error message

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package mesa-common-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libxatracker-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libgbm-dev-lts-trusty
>   E: Unable to locate package libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty

I also tried using `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty` 
but this does not work either as it gives me yet another error message

> Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty

How can i solve this issue and continue installation?